# C++ linked list values changing retroactively

Tags: c++, linked-list

**EDIT: Solution Code included at the end.**

I am trying to implement a linked list class that utilizes a node class as defined in the assignment. The below code block prints output as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Node class as provided
class node {
    void *info;
    node *next;
public:
    node (void *v) {info = v; next = 0; }
    void put_next (node *n) {next = n;}
    node *get_next ( ) {return next;}
    void *get_info ( ) {return info;}
};

// Linked list class
class list {
    //Start of the linked list
    node *start;
public:
    list (int v) {
        start = new node (&v);
    }

    void insert (int value, int place=-1) {
        node *temp = new node (&value);

        if (place == 0) {
            temp->put_next(start);
            start = temp;
        } else {
            node *before = start;
            for (int i = 1; before->get_next() != 0; i++) {
                if (i == place) { 
                    break;
                }
                before = before->get_next();
            }

            temp->put_next(before->get_next());
            before->put_next(temp);
        }
    }

    void remove(int place) {
        if (place == 0) {
            start = start->get_next();
        } else {
            node *curr = start;
            for (int i = 1; curr != 0; i ++) {
                if (i == place) {
                    curr->put_next(curr->get_next()->get_next());
                    break;
                }
                curr = curr->get_next();
            }
        }
    }

    void display() {
        for (node *current = start; current != 0; current = current->get_next()) {
            cout << *(static_cast<int*>(current->get_info())) << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    list *tst = new list(10);
    tst->display();
    cout << "Prepending 9" << endl;
    tst->insert(9,0);
    tst->display();
    cout << "Inserting 8" << endl;
    tst->insert(8,1);
    tst->display();
    cout << "Prepending 7" << endl;
    tst->insert(7,0);
    tst->display();

    tst->remove(0);

    cout << "Removed the first element:" << endl;
    tst->display();
    cout << endl;

//  cout << "Prepending 6" << endl;
//  tst->insert(6,0);
//  tst->display();

}
```

Creates this output:

```
10
Prepending 9
9
10
Inserting 8
9
8
10
Prepending 7
7
9
8
10
Removed the first element:
9
8
10
```

However, when I add this last statement to the end of the program flow in main:

```
tst->insert(6,0);
```

My output changes to this:

```
10
Prepending 9
9
10
Inserting 8
8
8
10
Prepending 7
7
7
7
10
Removed the first element:
134515798
134515798
10
```

What am I missing? How can adding a value later in execution change the output that happens before I even get to that point in the program flow?

I am using ideone.com as my IDE/to run the program, I've never had an issue before, but is that the issue?

**Solution**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Provided node class
class node {
    void *info;
    node *next;
public:
    node (void *v) {info = v; next = 0; }
    void put_next (node *n) {next = n;}
    node *get_next ( ) {return next;}
    void *get_info ( ) {return info;}
};

// List class template
template <class T>
class list {
    node *start;
public:
    list (T v) {
        start = new node (&v);
    }

    // Insert method
    void insert (T *value, int place=-1) {
        node *temp = new node (value);

        // If we're putting it at the beginning, then change the reference to start
        if (place == 0) {
            temp->put_next(start);
            start = temp;
        }

        // We're inserting it somewhere other than the beginning, handle appropriately
        else {
            node *before = start;

            // Loop to find preceeding node
            for (int i = 1; before->get_next() != 0; i++) {
                if (i == place) { 
                    break;
                }
                before = before->get_next();
            }

            // Insert after preceeding node, and point at subsequent node
            temp->put_next(before->get_next());
            before->put_next(temp);
        }
    }

    // Remove function
    void remove(int place) {

        // If we're removing hte beginning, then change start pointer
        if (place == 0) {
            start = start->get_next();
        }

        // Find node to remove
        else {
            node *curr = start;
            for (int i = 1; curr != 0; i ++) {
                if (i == place) {
                    // Cut target node out of list
                    curr->put_next(curr->get_next()->get_next());
                    break;
                }
                curr = curr->get_next();
            }
        }
    }

    // Print nodes
    void display() {
        for (node *current = start; current != 0; current = current->get_next()) {
            cout << *(static_cast<T*>(current->get_info())) << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    int nine = 9;
    int eight = 8;
    int seven = 7;
    int six = 6;
    int five = 5;

    cout << "Create list holding '10'" << endl;
    list<int> *tst = new list<int>(10);

    cout << "Prepending 9" << endl;
    tst->insert(&nine,0);

    cout << "Inserting 8 at 2nd place" << endl;
    tst->insert(&eight,1);

    cout << "Appending 7" << endl;
    tst->insert(&seven);

    cout << "Prepending 6" << endl;
    tst->insert(&six,0);

    cout << "Inserting 5 at 3rd place" << endl;
    tst->insert(&five,2);

    cout << "Show completed list:" << endl;
    tst->display();

    cout << "Removing the first element:" << endl;
    tst->remove(0);
    tst->display();

    cout << "Removing the last element:" << endl;   
    tst->remove(4); 
    tst->display();

    cout << "Removing the second element:" << endl;
    tst->remove(1);
    tst->display();
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?

Comment: Every line runs fine, just the output changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code, because you save pointers to local variables, variables that goes out of scope once the function returns.

The variable I'm talking about is the argument `value` inside the `insert` function, once the `insert` function returns that pointer is no longer valid.

The quick solution? Don't store pointers, store a list of integers. Or maybe make the list (and node) a templated class and store *by value*.

If you truly want a list that can contain anything, the consider using e.g. [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, the node class was provided as part of the assignment and has to be used in a linked list for this assignment, I know there are better ways to accomplish what is shown here. You did identify the issue, and I changed the way insert works to take a pointer to an int in scope in main, instead of a value. This has fixed my problems. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenBush If that's the case then my suggestion is that you allocate dynamically instead, because if you reuse the same variable for multiple inserts, then you insert the same pointer multiple times.

Comment: Yeah, I've revised my code, and included the final version below. I templated the class so it could handle any datatype, and instantiated the parameters in main and passed in pointers instead of the values themselves so they'd maintain scope with the main program flow. Thanks again for your help. I've been beating my head against this for a while.